# Uncertainty when a measurement is given as "between this number and that number"

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometry, error-analysis

A regulation soccer field for international play is a rectangle with a length between 100 m and 110 m and a width between 64 m and 75 m.

It then asked me to calculate the area which is easy but I don't know how many significant figures it should be. Its the "between 100 and 110" part that confuses me. What exactly does that mean about the uncertainty and for significant figures?

Answer (score 0):

Although the lengths are given as a range, they will actually be known very accurately - perhaps to within a cm. So these 100,10, 64 and 75 can be treated as exact numbers. Give all the significant figures.

Comment: Question asks me how many sig figs are appropriate when calculating area with those numbers. I said "1" , because the number 100 has 1 sig fig. The answer says it is "2" but doesnt explain why.